# Prove that wedge sum of $S^2$ and $S^1$ homotopy equivalent to the union of $S^2$ and it's diameter

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology

We have 2 topological spaces: wedge sum of $S^2$ and $S^1$ and the union of $S^2$ and it's diameter. Should prove that their spaces homotopy equivalent.

My ideas: we can see that these 2 spaces are not homeomorphic, because if we remove the point of contact of two spheres in the second space, the space will no longer be connected, but if we remove any point in the first space, it will still remain connected. That why we should use deformation retraction or third spaces to prove homotopy equivalence, but I don't know how.

Comment: By $S^2$ union its diameter do you just mean $S^2$, since the union of a set with one of its subsets is just the original set? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I think some information is lacking: is by union you mean as subsets of $S^2$, then the claim is false, and if you mean a disjoint union, then the claim is also false

Comment: Repeating verbatim what two separate commenters have clearly not understood is not going to help. If by $S^2\cup\textrm{diameter}$ you mean just $S^2$, then it is clearly false, and to prove this use the fundamental group which is a homotopy invariant. For one space it is trivial, and for the other it is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: He means $S^2$ together with a chord connecting two antipodal points.

Comment: @s.harp yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Construct the wedge $X=S^2\vee S^1$ as a quotient space $S^2\sqcup[0,1]/(N\sim 0,N\sim 1)$ where $N$ is the north pole of $S^2$. Now let $p:[0,1]\to S^2$ be a path such that $p(0)=N$ and $p(1)=S$ is the south pole. Now consider the one parameter family of spaces $X_t=S^2\sqcup[0,1]/(N\sim 0,p(t)\sim 1)$. Then $X=X_0$ and $X_1$ is the union of $S^2$ with the diameter. This deformation does not strictly give you a homotopy equivalence between the spaces, but should give the intuition, and perhaps you can adapt it into a rigorous proof if you need to.